# Update Queryset and Stay on the Same Page

Tags: django, django-views

I currently have a from that my users fill out. From there the site admin has to either approve or decline the form. I'd like to quickly approve or decline these entries. Here is the relevant `models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Submitted', 'Submitted'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Declined', 'Declined'),
    )

    user= models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=55, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Submitted')
```

Once the user submits it, I have a view that lists all instances where MyModel.status is Submitted. Here is that `views.py`

```
@staff_member_required
def review(request):
    pending = MyModel.objects.filter(status="Submitted")
```

Finally I have an approve view:

```
# views.py
@staff_member_required
def approve(request, id):
    MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).update(status="Approved")

#urls.py
url(r'^review/approve/(?P<id>[\w\-]+)/$', views.approve),
```

What I want to do is have a button I can click on to approve the form and have the accepted object disappear, as opposed to having to click a button to accept, then refresh the page and do the same thing for the next one. Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: in the template make three buttons -> on click make an `alert()` to make sure you didn't click the wrong one -> when inside the `alert` the final button is clicked, -> send Ajax call. No need to reload!
To view the content the user submitted I would do a simple `content` button. On click a modal opens with the data inside. Can also be done in Ajax (depends on how heavy the submitted data is)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by hansTheFranz if you want to prevent page reload, just write an ajax function that will update your model. In addition, I would advice to load all forms in your admin page (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/ to bulk generate instead of one by one), hide them all except first one and with ajax succeed function to hide the current one and show the following.

PS: dont forget to send CSRF token to your view, it's often a source of trouble when using ajax with Django.